# regular expression foo_bar_number to 2 strings [foo_bar, number]?

Tags: java, regex, split, expression

i'm kinda new to regular expressions. I have this case where i want to split many words like

"foo_bar_21", "bla_keks_38", etc. to

["foo_bar", "21"], ["bla_keks", "38"]

basically i want the last element which is always a number to be separated and the underscore before only that number removed.

How do I do that?

thanks for your help guys, very much appreciated.

*edit: i forgot to mention that i try to do this in java ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this regex:

```
^(.*)_(\d+)$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[bash_prompt$]echo $l
foo_bar_21
[bash_prompt$] i=${l##*_}; j=${l%%_[0-9]*}
[bash_prompt$] echo "i=$i, j=$j"
i=21, j=foo_bar
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, although i haven't found a way to apply this to java strings, any suggestions?